# My wallet can't have gone is possible

Tags: present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

It can't have gone : I will explain this sentence. **We do not know where it go or not**. And I strongly believe that it still stay.

When I know correctly, then following is possible ?

> I placed my wallet here. But it disappeared. **It can't have gone with legs (1)**.

Frequently we say "It goes since it has leg ?" or "It fly because it has wings ?" when our things are disappeared. Here we know the fact that wallet can not have legs so that we can use (1) ?

Comment: Can you try and explain what exactly you are asking? If you are simply asking if the sentence is correct, that is off-topic here. Can you say what you think may be wrong with the sentence?

Comment: You can say 'It can't have gone' meaning 'I can't believe it has disappeared', but 'It can't have gone with legs' is not a valid English sentence. I have heard people say something like 'It can't have suddenly sprouted legs' with reference to an object that has mysteriously disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the expression you are looking for is "it can't have *flown away*".

We also sometimes say "it can't have disappeared into thin air" as a way of expressing disbelief that something has seemingly gone from where we expected it to be.

You are not limited to idiomatic expressions though - there is no reason you couldn't be creative and write something like "my wallet can't have sprouted wings".